# Using ParticleJS with Gatsby

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, particles.js

I'm using ParticleJS React component with gatsby.

I start with fetching `npm install react-particles-js`.

I started with a very simple example :

```
import React from "react"
import Particles from 'react-particles-js';

export default () => (
  <div>
  <Particles params={{
        "particles": {
            "number": {
                "value": 50
            },
            "size": {
                "value": 3
            }
        },
        "interactivity": {
            "events": {
                "onhover": {
                    "enable": true,
                    "mode": "repulse"
                }
            }
      }
    }}/>
  </div>

)
```

The rendered HTML is something like this :

```
<div>
   <div id="tsparticles">
      <canvas class="tsparticles-canvas-el" width="3584" height="1792" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
      </canvas>
   </div>
</div>
```

Still, nothing is displayed! Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything already worked as expected. Just be careful that by default the particles displayed by the canvas are white. Hence, they will be invisible if the background is white as in my case.

Changed the particles to black and they appeared. Below a minimal working example :

```
<Particles
      params={{
        particles: {
          color: {
            value: "#000000"
          }
        }
      }}
    />
```

Answer (score 2):

That's a known issue using that library with Gatsby js, but there are workarounds, you can check this GitHub issue: https://github.com/Wufe/react-particles-js/issues/23
And here's a reproduction: https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-lake-i0c7z?file=/src/pages/index.js

Comment: Your answer pointed me in the right direction. It was simpler than that. My canvas did work. But the default color is what so it didn't appear. When changing color to black, I was able to see them.

Answer (score -1):

wrap it wit `return` like

```
export default () => (
  return (
/** yours here) 
)
```

Comment: I'm using gatsby and not plain react components